# How do you iterate over this array? I know this is very basic

Tags: arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(6)

for i in a:
    b[i]=a[i] + 1

print(b)
```

this is the error

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I want b to read `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`

Comment: You don't need loops with numpy: `b = a + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in array` returns the values, not the indices. To iterate over the indices, use `range(len(a))` instead of just `a`.

The corrected code:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i] = a[i] + 1
```

The better solution, if you're just looking for 1 to 6, is to do `np.arange(1, 7)`

Edit: As Paul points out, numpy has a much better solution than I knew. All you have to do is `b = a + 1`

Comment: if all the OP wants is to add 1 to each element of `a`, the best thing would be to take advantage of numpy's vectorized functionality and do `b = a + 1`.

Comment: Ah, did not know that! Yes, definitely use that instead.

Comment: Thank you guys very much. The simplification is also an added bonus. I just wanted to see how for loops work with arrays.